# How to search within date range for multi entities?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have the following tables:

- **CompanyHistory:** Id StartDate EndDate
- **CustomerHistory** Id CompanyId StartDate EndDate
- **CustomerPayment** Id CustomerId StartDate EndDate Amount

I want to make a report for to search for all payments and their customers and their companies within specific date range (firstDay,endDay).

I did this using this code for only CustomerPayment, and I have to do the same for CustomerHistory and companyHistory tables.

And the performance is really bad.

Is there any way to improve queries or I should change my DB design?

```
var payments= db.CustomerPayment.Where(s =>> 
             ((firstDay <= s.EndDate && lastDay >= s.StartDate) && 
              (lastDay <= s.EndDate || lastDay >= s.EndDate) && 
              (firstDay > s.StartDate || firstDay < s.StartDate)) ||
             ((s.EndDate == null) && ((firstDay >= s.StartDate) || 
              (firstDay <= s.StartDate && lastDay >= s.StartDate)));
```

Comment: Use [SQL Profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler) to get that query's SQL and then use [SQL Tuning Advisor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/dta/tutorial-database-engine-tuning-advisor) on that SQL to see which indexes are missing.

Answer (score 1):

1. You say you want every payment (payments are always done on an exact moment) so I'm confused why that would have both an end date and a start date. If possible, lose one of them.
2. A payment is inside your window if a start date is before the last day of your report **and** your end date surpasses the starting date of your report. Apparantly, endDate can have a null meaning infinite so I added that in the following clean, simple statement:

`var payments= db.CustomerPayment.Where(s =>> 
  (s.StartDate <= lastDay && (a.EndDate >= firstDay || a.EndDate == null));`

3. If performance of this query is still lacking, you simply have too many records in your database for performance. You can either write an index as @Uwe Keim suggested, or calculate once per month (or week or whatever your smallest reporting metric is) the amount of payments per customer and store those results in your database.